# Trouble with Tweepy output

Tags: python, json, tweepy

I'm trying to work with Tweepy output from a Twitter user's timeline. I have tried treating the output as JSON, to no avail. Below is how I've retrieved the data, and some of the attempts at working with the data and the subsequent errors I've received.

How I've retrieved the data:

```
user_timeline = api.user_timeline(screen_name='TechCrunch', count=5)
```

Partial output:

```
[Status(_api=, _json={'created_at': 'Tue Mar 24 18:02:08 +0000 2020', 'id': 1242512035159687169, 'id_str': '1242512035159687169', 'text': 'RT @Yair_Rosenberg: Please listen to...'''
```

Attempted code:

```
Timeline_result = json.loads(user_timeline)
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not ResultSet
```

Attempted code:

```
Timeline_result = json.dumps(user_timeline)
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: Object of type Status is not JSON serializable
```

The only way i've been able to extract anything readable from this data set has been when using the following-

```
user_timeline[0].text
```

Partial output:

```
'RT @Yair_Rosenberg: Please listen to Dr...'
```

Ultimately, i'd like to be able to extract all of the relevant information individually, i.e. 'id', 'id_str', 'text', etc...

Thank you all for the help. I've been banging my head against a wall on this for a while...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweepy's [user_timeline](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v2.3.0/api.html?highlight=user_timeline#API.user_timeline) returns a list of objects of type `Status`.

In order to access individual `id`, `id_str`, `text`, we can iterate over the `user_timeline` object like:

```py
user_timeline = api.user_timeline(screen_name='TechCrunch', count=5) 
for tweet in user_timeline:
    tweet._json['id_str']
```

Since every status has a tweet json, you may find its attributes [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object). Additionally, [here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/models.py#L83) is the actual implementation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for helping me get over this hump. I had tried iterating over the output, but was missing the ._json you included in the 'for loop.'